# How to block localhost from ufw

Tags: 18.04, firewall, ufw

im already tried

```
sudo ufw deny proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1 port 80,443,3306
```

but when i start /opt/lampp/lampp start and refresh localhost it's still work

Comment: did you stop and start the firewall?

Comment: I see from serverfault that this is not possible,  you need iptables https://serverfault.com/questions/473348/deny-from-localhost-with-ufw